# Trying to make a random speed generator

Tags: lua, roblox

Its on Roblox studio

Every 5 seconds the players speed changes

Im kind of new to coding

I tryed to use the math.random
I probably did it wrong

Tried to like use the output
I dont think it works like that

I do not know
PLEASE HELP

Comment: When you ask a question on StackOverflow, it is important to show that you have tried to solve this yourself first. Typically, you do that by sharing the code that you tried and an explanation of what isn't working. The way your question is currently phrased, it sounds like you are asking someone to write your code for you. So please update your question with the code you've tried and please include any errors you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

First insert a LocalScript in the PlayerGui then open the script for editing
in the scrpt type:

```
local MinimalSpeed = your minimal speed in numbers
local MaximalSpeed = your maximal speed in numbers
local LocalPlayer = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer
local Humanoid = LocalPlayer.Character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
function makespeed()
    Humanoid.WalkSpeed = math.random(MinimalSpeed,MaximalSpeed)
    wait(5)
end

while true do
    makespeed()
end
```

the default speed is 16 so type in what speed you want